# Is passing a float[] as ref float to unmanaged code a good idea?

Tags: c#, c, arrays, marshalling

I would like to pass a float[] to a C method. The C signature looks like:

```
EXTERN int process_raw(float *inBuffer, float *outBuffer);
```

in C# the signature is:

```
public static extern int process_raw(ref float inBuffer, ref float outBuffer);
```

will it be problematic to pass arrays with a ref to the first member:

```
process_raw(ref someArray[0], ref anotherArray[0])
```

thanks!

EDIT: Of course its important to know what the C code does with the floats: It will treat them as arrays and will read values from inBuffer and will write values to outBuffer. As discussed below, the question is whether the whole memory will be pinned during the PInvoke call?

EDIT 2: Another comment. I chose the ref float on purpose because i also wanted to do things like:

```
fixed(byte* outBuff = buffer)
{
    Process(ticks, ref aFloat, ref ((float*)outBuff)[0]);
}
```

In this case it should be no problem, because the pointer is fixed anyways, but the question for normal array as above remains.

Comment: Note that you should consider redesigning API to include sizes of "in" and "out" buffers. Especially if there is a chance that size of "out" buffer to have different length than "in" buffer. It'll also make marshaling easier.

Comment: in this case its clear, the method takes by definition 64 samples. but there are other methods like this which have a size argument but it left them out for the sake of simplicity. my only concern is the GC and if the memory will be pinned. the C code will read 64 values from inBuffer and will write 64 values to outBuffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no auto-pin involved in p/Invoke. P/Invoke is strictly performed via *marshalling*! (without unsafe code) To marshal means to allocate (unmanaged) memory and copy. Under covers there is probably a pin for the duration of the copy, but not for the duration of the native function call.

If you need to pass an array of 64 floats in and out of a native function you have two choices:

1. Marshall it through.
2. Use unsafe code to pin and pass the managed memory directly.

Here is the marshalled method:

```
[DllImport(...)]
private extern static int process_raw([In] float[] inBuffer, [Out] float[] outBuffer);
```

Note that I added the [In] and [Out] attributes as they tell the Marshaller (In) not to copy on the way out and (Out) not to copy on the way in. It's a good idea to always consider those attributes when writing a p/invoke declaration.

Here is the unsafe method:

```
[DllImport(...)]
private extern static unsafe int process_raw(float * inBuffer, float * outbuffer);

public static unsafe int Process(float[] inBuffer, float[] outBuffer)
{
    // validate for null and Length < 64
    fixed (float * pin = inBuffer)
    fixed (float * pout = outBuffer)
        return process_raw(pin, pout);
}
```

**Expanded Comment**

It is my understanding that the Marshaller is able to "under certain circumstances" choose to pin the managed memory instead of allocating unmanaged memory and copying. The problem with that is: What circumstances?

I don't know the answer, but I have a suspicion: When the native DLL is certain system DLLs. That's only a guess.

What this means to you and I is quite simple: Always begin with the marshalled method. If you're having performance issues and the profiler tells you that the native call is consuming a significant portion of time, then you can try the unsafe method and profile it again. If there is no significant improvement, then you're only hope is to optimize the native call.

Comment: thank you! so how would i write the signature then if i want to expose both possibilities? so that the programmer can use array or pointers as arguments? will it need two implementations?

Comment: @Tergiver: as an optimization the Marshaller will pin instead of copying blittable types, which includes 1D arrays.

Comment: See my expanded comment above. @thalm: I don't understand the question. You have both signatures above.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little ambiguous what you're trying to do here.  The native code could be treating the `float*` as a pointer to a `float` or an array of `float` values.

If the native code thinks it's a pointer to a single `float` then your code is just fine.  Having the `float` be a `ref` in managed and pointer in native will marshal correctly.

If the native code thinks it's an array of `float` values then you most likely have a problem.  This will work in the corner case it treats it as an array of length 1.  For any other length though you need to use an actual array in the managed signature

```
public static extern int process_raw(float[] inBuffer, float[] outBuffer);
```

Comment: +1, I'd add the OP's current approach would require the arrays to be pinned manually as the Marshaller does not understand their intent. (deleted my answer)

Comment: @sixlettervariables the CLR will auto-pin any memory which is passed to the PInvoke layer for the duration of the call. The pin should only be needed if the native pointer survives the PInvoke call

Comment: I was under the impression ref's to array elements did not trigger that behavior (or had believed P/Invoke problems of mine were related to that sort of code).

Comment: @sixlettervariables hmm, you may be right about the `ref` case. Found a reference that supports you needing to pin. Digging deeper http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx#S5

Comment: @sixlettervariables i've found more sources which dispute that article  and say that all passed memory is pinned for the duration of the PInvoke call. I believe that is correct with respect to `ref` (else **lots** of sample code MS produces is wrong). I'm still digging around though as this has me rather curious.  I'll write back if I find anything else interesting.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446538.aspx

Comment: I guess it all depends on what he's doing with the memory, he may get *lucky* and not need to pin; or you may be right and it may be Ok to not pin by design. Either way I've not found much help stepping outside the simple features of the P/Invoke Marshaller.

Comment: so yes, that's the question, will the whole array be pinned? the memory usage is as follows: the C code will read 64 values from inBuffer and will write 64 values to outBuffer.